# CQRS - Generating view counts for specific reads

Tags: design-patterns, cqrs

How to record how many times a given resource was read? You could do it on the read models itself but what if you have same logic in the commands side (microservices) that need that info? Is it ok for the readmodels to send commands back to the microservices to have this recorded that? I have never seen an example all these years which covered readmodels generations commands but I don't think I can get away from it. What is your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it ok for the readmodels to send commands back to the microservices to have this recorded that?

It's OK to send commands to your services from anywhere; you probably don't want that to be synchronous; but there's nothing fundamentally wrong with, for example, logging that somebody requested a view.

That said, accessing the read model is generally expected to be safe, in a similar sense to that used by [HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1).  Destructive side effects aren't usually built into the design of a read model.

Comment: I actually wanted to say raise and event, since sending a command would add to some extra level of coupling which I want to exist only the Web API. So is it safe to say that handling an event inside of my domain which was generated from outside of the domain (read models) would be equally OK? There might not be anything against it, but it is more that just logic, I might actually have some logic on the domain based on this. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: And thanks for the HTTP section, event tho I have been using CQRS for a good few years, haven't read that before (+1)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the answer to this question depends on whether the counter is relevant for your domain. The fact that you say that it is relevant for the write model is a hint that it actually is.

If it was *not* relevant for the domain, I would simply update a counter on every single access in the read model. Period.

If it actually *is* relevant for the domain, then this means that you need to trigger another command which then affects some kind of counter aggregate (or however you have modeled this). This then means that there are only two options where you can send this command: Either on the client-side, or from the read model itself.

To make sure that sending the command always happens, no matter which client accesses your read model, I would actually add it to the read model. For the write model, this is perfectly fine, as it doesn't care from where the commands come that it receives.

So, to cut a long story short: Yes, that's fine :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for you input :)